# AWS - Can you transfer your KMS key from one account to another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I have looked and only found allowing an external account to use the KMS key. But I want to decommission my old account later on. Is it possible to transfer your KMS key from your old account to a new account?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Like other AWS resources, KMS is a resource available to a specific account. I do not think you can transfer the resource. You would need to re create it under your new Account.